# How to add own css and js files to the build of Angular 2 App?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, bundle

Angular 2 automatically adds link to styles.css to the head and some scripts to the end of body of index.html.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
```

Where I can configure Angular to add also my own .css and .js files to the build?
P.S. I'm using CLI

Comment: Are you using `cli`?

Comment: @Kinduser yeap!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your `angular-cli.json` file and find `assets` array. Push the links inside of the files you want the `build` process to include.

```
"assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico",
    "styles.css",
    "d3.js",
],
```